# Office Powerpoint Ribbon menu item access?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, powerpoint

Is it possible from the Powerpoint slide, I can access to a Ribbon menu item?
For example, I have a checkbox under the Ribbon Menu. Now I want that when I click a shape, this checkbox should be checked?

The issue seems to be easy, but I cannot find a way to do it. Do you have any idea?
(prefer in C#)

[image]

**EDITED with CODE**

The custom ribbon menu

```
public partial class RibbonMenu
{
        private void RibbonMenu_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void ChangeCheckBox()
        {
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The CheckBox is changed");
              this.checkBox.Checked = true;
              this.checkBox.Label = "AAAAAAA"
        }

}
```

Catch the selection event

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
        private RibbonMenu menu;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject();
            Application.WindowSelectionChange   += new PowerPoint.EApplication_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(Application_WindowSelectionChange);

        }

        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            this.menu = new RibbonMenu();

            return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[]
             {
                  this.menu                  
             });
        }

        private void Application_WindowSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection Sel)
        {
            //.... Check if the selection is a shape's selection
            this.menu.ChangeCheckBox();         
        }
}
```

The Result is the message box **"The CheckBox is changed"**" is appeared, but the checkbox is not cheched and the label is not changed to "AAAAAA"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Globals to access the Office Ribbon Menu Item as follow:

```
private void Access_All_Ribbons_Globals()
{
    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.comboBox1.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the `Application.WindowSelectionChange` event for this.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743918%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> Occurs when the selection of text, a shape, or a slide in the active document window changes, whether in the user interface or in code.

It will give you a `Selection` object which you can use further on.

Signature of the event handler:

```
void (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Selection selection)
```

Comment: The selection event is not a problem for me. My question is about when we catch the selection event, is it possible to update the Ribbon menu item? Like change the value of the checkbox (under the ribbon menu) from false to true?

Comment: I tried to access the Ribbon menu and update the checkbox, change its checked value, change its label, but it does not change anything

Comment: @chipbk10: What checkbox? I see no checkbox in your (absent) code.

Comment: @chipbk10: I will give it a try and come back to you.

Comment: The general idea is to have the ribbon or control's onLoad event pass a reference to itself to a routine in your code; then as necessary, your code call's the control's invalidate method; the control then queries your code for values like "Am I checked or not?".  The Martin/Puls/Hennig RibbonX book has VBA examples of this (I think I mentioned the book to you in another thread).

Comment: I am still using the Standard Ribbon menu, and have no time to convert to RibbonX. So with the Standard Ribbon Menu, it's impossible to access its items at run-time?